# htaccess rewrite URL

Tags: .htaccess

If I have an URL that looks like the following,

/iamawebpage.html

can I rewrite to something like, iamnotawebpage?

basically change the whole URI.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteBase /
       RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

This in .htaccess should work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Also, why did you put [R]? It doesn't sound like he wants to redirect.

Comment: I guess the [R] can be removed then. I'm a bit new to mod_rewrite.